# WCF derived DataContract does not inherit base DataContract's property

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance

Below is my WCF DataContract base class

```
  [DataContract]
    public class BaseClass
    {
       //some datamembers
    }
```

And here is my derived class....

```
 [DataContract]
    public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string ProductName{get;set;}
    }
```

Due to some change in requirements, I am adding one more derived type which is also having same property 'ProductName'.

So code structure now is....

```
 [DataContract]
        public class BaseClass
        {
           //some datamembers
           [DataMember]
           public string ProductName{get;set;}
        }

[DataContract]
        public class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
        {
           //[DataMember]
           //public string ProductName{get;set;}  property moved to base class
        }

[DataContract]
            public class DerivedClass2 : BaseClass
            {
               //some datamembers specific to DerivedClass2
            }
```

so I moved property 'ProductName' to base class. But now when existing datacontract is been called from client which returns me list of Derivedclass1, I don't see productName in response. Somehow, my DerivedClass1 is not ineriting productName property from base.
What could be the reason? Am I making any mistake while writing code?

Comment: are the base class members also annotated with `DataMember` attributes? edit: nevermind... read the post more closely. Have you regenerated the service reference from the caller?

Comment: It is working fine! I have tried it. No issue

Comment: what do you mean by `I don't see productName in response`? Is `ProductName` property set to null? Have you updated proxy definition on client?

Answer (score 0):

Try use [KnownType(typeof(BaseClass))] attribute on derived classes and also ensure service reference updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working fine!

[image: Base Type]

Here is the SubClass **SychRequests**

[image: Child class]

And this is what I got in Intellisense.

[image: Working]

What else you are missing, can't say anything. If you can't see **ProductName** in response then that might be due to you are not sending it in your request.